# echo correct message without slash

Tags: php, database

my output is:

```
Hei\\\\r\\\
Dette er en test, og jeg savner deg
```

and in my database it is:

```
Hei\\r\\nDette er en test, og jeg savner deg
```

what im sending into the database:

```
Hei
Dette er en test, og jeg savner deg
```

with the following code:

```
<td><textarea cols="50" rows="10" name="innhold" value="<? echo $innholdp; ?>" class="textarea"></textarea></td>
    $innhold  = addslashes($_POST['innhold']);
    $innholdp = addslashes($_GET['innhold']);

    $innhold  = mysql_escape_string($innhold);
    $innholdp = mysql_escape_string($innholdp);


mysql_query("INSERT INTO `innboks` SET `til`='$tilp', `fra`='$data->login', `emne`='$emne', `dato`='$dato', `innhold`='$innhold', `lest`='Nei', `slettet`='nei'") or die('Error: '.mysql_error());
```

( the code was just ripped off my file, this is everything with the code to do).

so my question is, how do i get it to be as i imputted? without the slash and everything clean?

edit:

my file:

```
    $userinsms = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `sms_kunder` WHERE `brukerid`='".$id."' LIMIT 1");

    $cursmsfirmid = @mysql_result($userinsms, NULL, "firmaid");
    $firmq = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `sms_firma` WHERE `id`='".$cursmsfirmid."'");

    if($data->level > 0) {

    $firmadata = @mysql_fetch_object($firmq);




    $til      = addslashes($_GET['til']);
    $tilp     = addslashes($_POST['til']);
    $emne     = addslashes($_POST['emne']);
    $emnep    = addslashes($_GET['emne']);
    $innhold  = addslashes($_POST['innhold']);
    $innholdp = addslashes($_GET['innhold']);

    $til      = mysql_escape_string($til);
    $tilp     = mysql_escape_string($tilp);
    $emne     = mysql_escape_string($emne);
    $emnep    = mysql_escape_string($emnep);
    $data->login   = mysql_escape_string($data->login);
    $innhold  = mysql_escape_string($innhold);
    $innholdp = mysql_escape_string($innholdp);
    $id       = mysql_escape_string($id);

    $getsperre = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `sperrer` WHERE `brukerid`='$data->id' AND `sperre`='pm'");
    $sperre = mysql_fetch_object($getsperre);

        $aa = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `[users]` WHERE `login`='$tilp'");
    $tilbruker = mysql_fetch_object($aa);

    $venter = $sperre->sperretil - $time;
    $ventingz = $time + 20;

    if(isset($_POST['send'])){
         if(mysql_num_rows($getsperre) == 1){
            echo "<div class=\"info\">Du må vente i <b><span id=\"vent\">".$venter."</span></b> sekunder før du kan sende ny PM</div>";
        /*} elseif($tilp == $data->login){
            echo "<div class=\"mislykket\">Du kan ikke sende meldinger til deg selv!</div>";*/



        } elseif(empty($tilp) || empty($emne) || empty($innhold)){
            echo "<div class=\"mislykket\">Alle felt må fylles ut!</div>";
        } elseif($tilbruker->health <= 0){
            echo "<div class=\"mislykket\">Brukeren du vil sende en melding til er død!</div>";
        } else {


            mysql_query("INSERT INTO `innboks` SET `til`='$tilp', `fra`='$data->login', `emne`='$emne', `dato`='$dato', `innhold`='$innhold', `lest`='Nei', `slettet`='nei'") or die('Error: '.mysql_error());
            echo "<div class=\"vellykket\">Meldingen er sendt til ".$tilp."! Meldingen kostet ".number_format($firmadata->pris)." kr</div>";
        }
    }

?>
<form action="" method="post">
    <tr><table width="60%" class="C2" align="center" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2">
            <th colspan="2"><center>Send melding</center></th>
        </tr>
            <tr class="uhead">
                <td>Til:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="til" value="<? echo $til; ?>" class="input"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="ehead">
                <td>Emne:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="emne" value="<? echo $emnep; ?>" class="input"></td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="uhead">
                <td>Melding:</td>
                <td><textarea cols="50" rows="10" name="innhold" value="<? echo $innholdp; ?>" class="textarea"></textarea></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="ehead">
                <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="send" value="Send PM" class="submit"></td>
            </tr>           
        </table>
</form>

<?
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you call 'addslashes'. If you don't, those slashes won't be added.

Comment: so addslashes adds slashes? well i never!

Comment: When i took away the addslashes, no difference at all.

Comment: I mean, you escaped it too much before putting it in the database. If you want to remove the excess of slashes from the values in the database, you can use `stripslashes`.

Comment: Did you notice that your script doesn't echo the values from the database at all? You execute three queries, but you hardly use information from them. At least not for displaying.